# How to swap 2 jPanel places?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So I created a new jFrame and in it I have 2 jPanels - jPanel1 and jPanel2.

I need these 2 jPanels to swap places, the first one goes to the place of the second, and the second to the place of the first (with everything that will be inside jPanels).

What is the best way to do this?

[image]

Comment: See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) It is probably better to follow an entirely different strategy, but the question does not give enough detail to determine what strategy is best. For example, if the two panels contain the same components displaying different data, the best approach is to have a model representing both sets of data, change the model, than update the existing panels to reflect the model. **General tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). ..

Comment: .. 2) Use *descriptive names* for components, for example, if the panels had been named `HusbandDetails` and `WifeDetails`  it would eb obvious they contained data (and components) of a similar nature that can be served by a single `SpouseDetails` and used in the alternate way suggested in the first comment.

Comment: Agreed with @AndrewThompson alternatively do take a look at the java example for JPanel [flowlayouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) `JPanel#setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);`  or `JPanel#setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);` might be want you want. You need to call `JPanel#validate();` and `JPanel#repaint();` after the above for it to actually change.

Comment: I agree with @AndrewThompson. Also, you lack to describe what the trigger is. In other words, what event causes these panels to "swap"? There are way too many details to formulate a solution to this problem.

Comment: @hfontanez for example button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;    

public class Class {
    static JFrame frame;
    static JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        panel1.add(new JLabel("Panel 1"));
        panel2.add(new JLabel("Panel 2"));

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);

        new Timer(2000,e -> {
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
            frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the layout you use in your parent panel, but basically, you must remove both components (content1 and content2) from the common parent panel and add them again at the other position.

I made a simple example with a (horizontal) flow layout and two panels on it with just one label on it - but it should work for more complex panels, too.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TestFrame f = new TestFrame();

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JPanel pnl1 = new JPanel();
        pnl1.add(new JLabel("My first label"));

        JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();
        pnl2.add(new JLabel("My second label"));

        f.getContentPane().add(pnl1);
        f.getContentPane().add(pnl2);

        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        // wait 2 seconds and switch panels
        System.out.println("before sleep");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("after sleep");

        // remove the old content - could be more "precise" in real world - not just remove all components
        f.getContentPane().removeAll();

        // add the components in different order (in flow layout)
        f.getContentPane().add(pnl2);
        f.getContentPane().add(pnl1);

        // render again
        f.revalidate();
    }
}
```